# pipenv - 'pew' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, pipenv

Why can't I enter the `pipenv shell`?

```
PS C:\Users\...\desktop\projects\myproject> pip freeze
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
configparser==3.5.0
Django==1.11
django-debug-toolbar==1.9.1
django-extensions==1.9.9
django-extra-views==0.9.0
djangorestframework==3.7.7
djaodjin-survey==0.1.7
enum34==1.1.6
flake8==3.5.0
idna==2.6
jsonfield==2.0.2
mccabe==0.6.1
pathlib==1.0.1
pew==1.1.2 <---------------------------------- it's right bloody here
pipenv==9.0.3
psutil==5.3.1
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
pycodestyle==2.3.1
pyflakes==1.6.0
pytz==2017.3
rebar==0.1
requests==2.18.4
shutilwhich==1.1.0
six==1.11.0
sqlparse==0.2.4
typing==3.6.2
urllib3==1.22
virtualenv==15.1.0
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
```

So `pew` is definitely installed.

```
PS C:\Users\...\desktop\projects\myproject> pipenv shell
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
New python executable in C:\Users\...\.virtualenvs\myproject-bRnmVZJC\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

Virtualenv location:
'pew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

But somehow not when I enter the `pipenv shell` (so that I can install packages that weren't installed with `pipenv`)

Comment: You may want to execute your commands with a specific version of python. I.e. `python3.6 -m pip freeze`. Then you know for sure what version your command is using. This may not be the problem, but it might be.

Comment: @FamousJameous I only have 2.7 on this machine. But now that you mention it, I believe pipenv really only plays well with 3 - so I'll move to python 3 and try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had installed `pipenv` using Python 2.7

To fix, I [installed both Python 2.7 and 3.4](https://datascience.com.co/how-to-install-python-2-7-and-3-6-in-windows-10-add-python-path-281e7eae62a) and set paths for both so that `python2` runs 2.7 and `python3` runs 3.4.

Then I installed `pipenv` using python3, and initiated a `pipenv` running in python 2.7.

```
python3 -m pip install --user pipenv
cd C:\Users\...\desktop\projects\myproject>
```

then I [set my user base's binary directory to my PATH](http://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/#installing-pipenv) and added

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python36\Scripts
```

to my PATH, then

```
pipenv --two install
pipenv shell
```

and voilà!

```
Launching subshell in virtual environment. Type 'exit' to return.
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.192]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```